# TCPDF - AJAX - Download file without saving it to webserver from AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdf, tcpdf

I have an AJAX call to the `create_pdf.php` page:

```
$('body').on('click', '.PrintButtonWithClass', function (event) {
    var1 = $('#id1').val();
    var2 = $('#id2').val();
    dataString='var1='+var1+'&var2='+var2+'&pdf_name=PdfName&pdf_creator=myname';

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'post',
        url: '/path/to/createpdf/file/create_pdf.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
});
```

In `create_pdf.php` I tried to use this line to download the file:

```
$pdf->Output(str_replace(' ','_',utf8_decode($_POST['pdf_name'])).'.pdf', 'D');
```

I tried also the `FD` and `I` parameters with no success, the file does not get downloaded.

How can I force downloading the file created without saving it to the webserver and without redirecting user to any other page? I want him to stay on the same page, and that the browser pops up a (download or preview dialog box) for the PDF. Is there any way to do it?

EDIT :  create_pdf.php is Waiting for POST variables. and uses them to create the HMTL for the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to submit the form to a new window( like a popup ):

```
<form method="post" id="myform" action="your_url">
    <input name="param1">
</form>
```

And in javascript

```
// create popup window
var wind = window.open('about:blank', '__foo', 'width=700,height=500,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');

// submit form to popup window
$("#myform").attr("target", "__foo");
```

Do not forget to send content-type header from php:

```
header("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
```

Edit: 
Browsers should display your pdf content and also show download or print options. 
The code is not tested but I think it would do what you requested;

Comment: I do not submit any form, I just have a 'Print' button that does the AJAX call when clicked, no form is submitted. I just get all the infos I need from the current page and send  them to create_pdf.php

Comment: You can create a dynamic form which can be submitted on button press.

Comment: create inputs like so: `var fields = $("<input>", {name: 'var1', type: 'text'});
$( "<form>", {target : '__foo', method : "post"} ).append( fields).submit();`

Comment: Please check this page: [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/post-form-popup-window-javascript-jquery/) . It mostly resumes to my previous comment.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you have to add form creation code in button click callback.

Comment: Do you think this is the best solution for me ? As I will need to send  different types of variables to the create_pdf.php page, (arrays, strings, numbers)  and also I do  heavy work with the variables I send

Comment: Place all your needed data in an object and apply JSON.stringify on it. Use a single input field and set its value to previously created json string.

Comment: In your php script you can use `extract(json_decode($_POST['created_input_name']))` if you want to access each array_key directly.

Comment: As I can see, you have already some input fields in the page. Why don't you wrap those fields in a <form> and simply submit it in the dynamically created popup?

Comment: I did not opt for that solution, instead I grab what I need ans send it directly, I thought it was a lot easier, I don't think I will be going for your solution, I am already invested in the first one.

Comment: It's the same thing, just with max 10 lines of additional code. Also you can clone your input fields and append them to dynamic form. That way you don't have to bother about serializing those values: `$( "#id1" ).clone().appendTo( form);`. You can create an array with ids which need to be moved and do a foreach through them to make your code cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around for my problem.

I did an `AJAX` call inside another `AJAX` call.

the first `AJAX` call creates the file on webServer and opens the file in a new Window.

In his success parameter I do the following:

The second `AJAX` call that deletes the file from Server.

```
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'post',
                url: '/path/to/create_pdf.php',
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) {

                window.open(
                  data,
                  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
                );


                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    dataString2 = 'Downloaded=true';
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'post',
                                url: '/path/to/create_pdf.php',
                                data: dataString2,
                                success: function (data) { alert(data); }, // handler if second request succeeds 
                            });
                }, 5000);



                    },

                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this answer to my similar request : [send a csv file from php to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101096/send-a-csv-file-from-php-to-browser/34101142#34101142)

I needed to (1) get and display a pdf in another window; and
(2) get a CSV file and prompt for saving.

I have 2 simple buttons on the page (http://potoococha.net/) for each.  Here is the code:

```
function getCSVText(evt)  {

  if (currentChecklistCountry)  {

    var form = $('<form method="post" action="../php/sendCSV.php?country=' + currentChecklistCountry + '"></form>');

    $('body').append(form);

    form.submit();

    form.remove();
  }
  else  checklistCountryButton.classList.add("needsAttention");
}

function openChecklistPage()  {

   if (!currentChecklistCountry)  {
       checklistCountryButton.innerHTML = "Select Country";
       checklistCountryButton.classList.add("needsAttention");
       return;
    }

   if (gNumDays == undefined) gNumDays = 12;

   vars = "?country="     + currentChecklistCountry;
   vars += "&num_days="   + gNumDays;
   vars += "&line_nos="   + lineNumbers.checked;
   vars += "&left_check=" + leftCheck.checked;
   vars += "&endemics="   + showEndemics.checked;
   vars += "&sci_names="  + !sciNames.checked;
   vars += "&italics="    + !italics.checked;

   window.open( '../php/makePDF.php' + vars, '_blank' );
}
```

So the getCSVText() methods downloads a file using a temporary form appended and then immediately removed, and openChecklistPage() successfully opens another browser window with a pdf file.   The pdf file is never saved on the server.  The CSV file is already stored there and just retrieved.  Perhaps you can modify the code for your purposes.